Can Sanskrit Manushya मनुष्य and English "Man" be traced back to a common PIE root?
The dictionary gives मनुष्य =  a man, human being
Are there multiple PIE roots related to "man" that have reflexes in the attested languages?

Can you elaborate (as requested in the close reason)? There are multiple directions this could go. If you look at an IE cognate dictionary, they put Sanskrit manushya मनुष्य and English "man" in the same entry '*mánus' with lots of Germanic cognates and Slavic too ('muzh') and Sanskrit (मनु manu, मानव manava and मनुष्य manushya)

I am done tailoring my interactions to the hyper-precisian rules that seem to exist here.  The question is perfectly clear, within the rules.  If the powers that be want it closed, bless their heart.. @mitch

S K, I've voted to reopen... you can too.

I don't think I have the privilege of reopening closed questions @mitch

S K, did you try?

I don't see a clickable link to reopen @mitch

S K, OK I thought even if you don't have enough rep to vote to reopen in general, you could still vote to reopen your own questions. Sorry. I've posted a link to [ELU.SE] chat, there might be some takers there

per the notice at the top of this question: "questions asking for the origin of words or phrases are off-topic unless they demonstrate that there is a reasonable assumption of systematicity, by situating themselves within a historical context of language change or contact." IMO this question has not met the condition of demonstrating a reasonable assumption of systematicity and does not situate itself within the historical context of language change or contact. Therefore, at this stage I support it remaining closed

It may be related:
https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=Manu
"Mon" also seems linked at 'g.' in this PIE reference,
"from Sanskrit manuḥ, man, from Indo-Iranian *manu‑"
